JPA composite key class for join table containing object references vs only containing ids
I'm trying to set up a join table to map a set of items to groups (in a many-to-many relationship) that can also have extra columns in addition to the object ids. I'm trying to use the object ids to create a composite key for the join table. As I understand it, the typical way to achieve this is to create a model/entity class for the join table, then have a separate embeddable composite key class which gets embedded into the join table class. I've found a lot of examples online, and I've noticed they seem to do this in one of two general ways:

The embeddable composite key class contains only the ids for the associated objects along with @Column annotations, while the join table class contains the actual object references and @ManyToOne mappings, such as in this example:

https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/

The embeddable composite key class contains references to the actual objects along with the @ManyToOne mappings, while the join table class contains @AssociationOverride and @JoinColumn annotations for their ids, such as in this example (scroll about halfway down the page to "Solution #2: Using Composite Key"):

https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-in-join-table-example
I've also seen some examples that seem to do both, which frankly just confused me even more.
MY ACTUAL QUESTION:
What are the advantages and disadvantages to each approach? Why might you prefer one or the other, or is one generally considered preferable? I have a fair amount of general programming experience, but I'm relatively new to ORM and back-end/database stuff specifically, and I was hoping someone with more experience would be kind enough to take the time and explain this to me (seriously, nothing I could find online talks about this difference at all).
Thanks so much!
